# How to storage the "\" in database?

Tags: java, mysql, navicat

I write a method to store a string in navigate, but the string is like this:

```
"data\510000RS\Other\"
```

So, it is crash:

```
 [SQL] call P_A_OperReg_Bio("liaomalin", "511321199001031598", "P_1", "http:p_1......", "http://p1_url1..", "md5_p1_md51", "http://p1_url2..", "md5_p1_md52", "http://p1_url3..", "","data\510000RS\Other\", "20170202", "", @a);
SELECT @a; 
 [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '20170202", "", @a);
SELECT @a' at line 1
```

The snapshot:

[image]

How to solve this issue?

---

If I have the string :

```
 data\510000RS\Other\
```

How can I transform it to :

```
"data\\510000RS\\Other\\"
```

Comment: Escape it by changing it to `\\\`.

Comment: @Steve Smith, how to transform "\" to "\\" ?? if I have the String ("data\510000RS\Other\")

Comment: in what way do you "have" that string? Note that `"data\510000RS\Other\"` is not a valid java expression to begin with. Is your *actual* string data\510000RS\Other\?

Comment: where do you get that string from? Are you writing it in your java source, is it some user input? You should not have to do anything when writing your java code to get the `\` into the database if you use a proper framework and / or prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape if with another slash before it:

> "data\\510000RS\\Other\\"

**If it's inside a program, DON'T DO THAT, it's unsecure! Use prepared statements.**

Example in JAVA: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: How to transform "data\510000RS\Other\" to "data\\510000RS\\Other\\" ?

Comment: @lme in which programming language?

Comment: I use java @Tom

Comment: `String.replace('\\', '\\\\');`

Comment: Prepared statements in java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: @SteveSmith It's not secure to do that! If it's not manual, prepared statements are mandatory to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is used as escape character in DBs. 
you can use two backslashes, instead of one for the producing the result or inserting the record.

```
"data\\510000RS\\Other\\"

Insert into table Values(1, "data\\510000RS\\Other\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed you can solve it by escaping the slah(\) by replacing all the slasshes with double slash.

I suggest to use `escapeSql(String str)` of `apache.commons.lang`.

```
org.apache.commons.lang;

StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(String str)
```

This method will not only escape the slash but also the other characters which cause issues while inserting into DB